# Strange way of printing Binary Search Tree C++ with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I was going through a lecture and it showed some code that prints out a binary search tree recursively like this

```
void printTree(node *t){
    if(t!=NULL){
        printTree(t->left);
        cout<<t->key<<endl;
        printTree(t->right);
     }
 }
```

I understand what it is doing but I don't understand the pointers.  The function is passing a pointer to a node yet in the 'cout' line, it is trying to access the key value in the node struct without dereferencing it first.  What I mean is, shouldn't it be something like

```
cout<<(*t)->key<<endl;
```

instead?

Comment: ahh. I think I am mixing up my (.)'s with my (->)'s. My bad, sorry

Comment: -> dereferences the pointer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, `->` is a dereferencing operator.
You can make a choice:

`cout<<t->key<<endl;`
or
`cout<<(*t).key<<endl;`

Answer (score 0):

But DEFINITELY not "(*t)->key" - that'd be a double deref and probably a compile error if not a crash.